# Is there a library to get country code from currency code in react in order to pass it to react country flag?

Tags: reactjs

Problem:

I am passing atm:

```
<ReactCountryFlag countryCode={accountInfo.currency_code} svg />
```

But my accountInfo.currency_code is for instance EUR or DKK or CAD and I need to pass EU or DK in order to let work my ReactCountryFlag. I was wondering if there is a method or library that can convert this in a simpler way instead of having a custom object with plus 190 country codes conversions. I do not know how many country we support, possibly all and I need to be sure to get all the flag if needed.

any tips ?

Comment: Something like this npm package [(iso-country-currency)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-country-currency) might work. But in your case it seems complicated cause one currency can have many countries.

Comment: Since currency doesn't directly map to flags (A currency can be used in multiple countries, and occasionally, a country can have multiple curacies) and you presumably need it to be 1-1, that "custom object with plus 190 country codes conversions" is probably a cleaner solution than pulling in other peoples opinionated lists in the form of a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-> I think you can use this library this way to achieve your desired output:

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-country-currency

-> Create one function which will convert your currency code to country ISO name this way:

```
const ConvertFunction = (currencyCode) => {
    return getISOByParam('currency', currencyCode);
};
```

Please read library [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-country-currency#documentation) for more info.

**Note: I have found few other libraries but haven't used (You can explore if you want to try it out)**

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-to-currency
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-to-currency

Later on, you can pass output directly into your component. Let me know, If you've any questions.